No way to hide other databases from an SSMS user in Sql Server
This is a very long running issue for me. I have tried all the solutions.
All I want is for customers to be able to use SSMS to connect via a read-only connection to their database so they can see their database listed in SSMS, and read data from their own database. and NOT allow them to see all the other database names in the SSMS Server Explorer.
The only close solutions are to provider OWNER access to a DB which forces that DB to appear only. But of course you cant provide owner access to a user.
So yes having googled this for a good 5 years hoping one day it will be supported, I am just shocked it gets left out.

Does this answer your question? How do you configure a MS SQL Server to prevent exposing all database names and logins to any authenticated user?

I found this post:
How do you configure a MS SQL Server to prevent exposing all database names and logins to any authenticated user?
It was in the "Related" topics next to your question, maybe it will help you?
Basicaly:
To hide databases to all LOGINS, remove/revoke "VIEW ANY DATABASE" permission from the public server role
http://sqlism.blogspot.com/2014/10/preventing-logins-and-users-to-see.html
